# Problemas al conectar a multiples cuentas de github con diferentes claves ssh

Tags: github, ssh

Me esta sucediendo algo extraño, tengo 1 app, en la que tengo que subirla a 2 cuentas diferentes de github, sin embargo a pesar de que creo los ssh-keygen con nombres distintos:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "clave1" -f /home/user/.ssh/clave1
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "clave2" -f /home/user/.ssh/clave2
```

Solo puedo lograr conectar con una cuenta de github, ya que la otra me da error de permiso al intentar realizar la subida, a pesar de que he verificado en varias ocaciones que la key es la misma con la cuenta a la que quiero conectar, hasta la he vuelto a pegar nuevamente, ademas tengo mi .ssh/config

```
Host host1
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/clave1"

Host host2
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/clave2"
```

¿Que podria estar pasando? Agradezco cualquier sugerencia, talvez este obviando algo, saludos!

Comment: Cómo tienes configurados los remotos de cada repo?

Comment: Puedes pegar el mensaje de error? Tienes permisos suficientes en el repositorio destino? Error de permisos no es lo mismo que error de autenticación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente, a la hora de conectarse a github, cualquier subdominio funciona. Sin embargo, [por defecto el comportamiento de ssh](https://serverfault.com/questions/450796/how-could-i-stop-ssh-offering-a-wrong-key/450807#450807) es probar todas las llaves, y en tu caso probará la primera llave antes de la segunda. Eso se puede prevenir usando `IdentitiesOnly yes`. De manera que tu `~/.ssh/config` quedaría:

```
Host clave1.github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/clave1"
IdentitiesOnly yes

Host clave2.github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/clave2"
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Y al clonar tus repos, usas:

```
git clone git@clave1.github.com:hectorhernandez/proyecto1.git
git clone git@clave2.github.com:hectorhernandez/proyecto2.git
```

Si ya clonaste los proyectos, puedes usar por ejemplo

```
git remote --set-url origin git@clave2.github.com:hectorhernandez/proyecto2.git
```

O bien editar a mano tu `./.git/config` en cada proyecto

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda Amenadiel, a pesar de que habia agregado el [ IdentitiesOnly yes ] aun asi no funcionaba, el agregar el alias del hostname directamente a la repo a conectar ha dado en el punto, Saludos! =D

Answer (score 1):

Yo añadiría ambas claves privadas al agente de autenticación. Es una solución mucho más sencilla y no supone un problema de seguridad en tu caso particular ya que ambos repositorios viven en GitHub.

```
ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/clave1
ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/clave2
```

Esto que te recomiendo no requiere editar el archivo de configuración de SSH. De esta forma le estás diciendo a tu cliente SSH que pruebe ambas claves a la hora de auteticarse.

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda Pancho Jay, es una forma bastante sencilla de solucionar el problema =D